# Unable to POST video file input using JS FormData object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, form-data

I actually did a lot of research and tried different ways to upload a video file using JQuery's `$.ajax()` and `FormData`. I am using an updated version of Chrome and Firefox and aware that uploading of file using `$.ajax()` is possible for **jQuery 1.6** and up. Right now I'm using **jQuery-3.3.1.js**

For whatever reason, I still can't make it work. I am getting an empty data when I echo `$_FILES['myFile']['name'];`

**view.php**

```
<div class="modal_body">
    <form class="container_UserInfo" id="modalForm_uploadVideo">
        <label class="modal_label" id="modalLbl_browseVideo">
        Select Video
        <input type="file" name="myFile" class="modalbtn_browseFiles" id="modalBtn_choose_video_file" value="Select Video" accept="video/*"/><br>
        </label>
    </form>
</div>

<button class="btn_modalFooter" id="modalBtn_uploadVideo_upload" name="modalBtnName_uploadVideo_upload">
    Upload
</button>
```

**view.js**

```
$('#modalBtn_uploadVideo_upload').on('click',function(event){
    if(hasInputFileLoaded()){
        uploadVideo();
    }else{
        alert("No file input.");   
    }
});

function uploadVideo() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', $('#modalBtn_choose_video_file')[0].files[0]);
    console.log($('#modalBtn_choose_video_file')[0].files[0]); // console displays the selected file info.
    $.ajax({
        url: 'controller/upload_video.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,  // tells jQuery not to process the data
        contentType: false,  // tells jQuery not to set contentType
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (x, e) {
            if (x.status == 0) {
                alert('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.');
            } else if (x.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested URL not found.');
            } else if (x.status == 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error.');
            } else if (e == 'parsererror') {
                alert('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed.');
            } else if (e == 'timeout') {
                alert('Request Time out.');
            } else {
                alert('Unknown Error.\n' + x.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**upload_video.php**

```
$myFile = $_FILES['myFile']['name'];
echo "myFile: " . $myFile;
```

`echo "myFile: " . $myFile;` displays:

> myFile:

This line:

```
console.log($('#modalBtn_choose_video_file')[0].files[0]); // console displays the selected file info.
```

shows me the information of the file that was selected and I'm sure it's not empty.

I dont know what's missing. It's able to pick up and run the upload_video.php script but gets nothing in `$_FILES[]`

I'd like to reiterate that the `<form>` is contained within a **modal** `div`. I don't know if it has anything to do with the problem.

Please help. I'd appreciate any suggestion.

Thank you.

**** EDIT ******

This is what I'm getting in **XHR->Headers->Request Payload** of Google's Developer Tools.

**Request Payload**

```
------WebKitFormBoundarybqKoBuiQ9WumYuTo
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="How to Configure Nginx VirtualHost in Ubuntu.mp4"
Content-Type: video/mp4
```

And for **Request Headers**

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 20360818
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarybqKoBuiQ9WumYuTo
Cookie: PHPSESSID=q669bu6jqodkpqpvu2hructsm7
Host: localhost
Origin: http://localhost
Referer: http://localhost/cai/landingpage.php
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

I've added the `enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"` as suggested and `var_dump($_FILES);` and `var_dump($_POST)` but keep getting

`NULL` or `array(0){}`

I also replaced `myFile` with `file` in `$_FILES[][]`

```
$myFile = $_FILES['file']['name'];
echo "myFile: " . $myFile;
```

but did nothing to fix my problem.

What other troubleshooting can I do?

******* end of edit *******

Comment: when you inspect the XHR request do you see a full payload in the request? The suspicion I had here was to do with the `Content-Type` header

Comment: Also not sure whether FormData alone will automatically specify the correct enctype when used this way. I would add that to the form, and then simply pass the form to the Formata constructor. Plus, do a var_dump of both $_FILES and $_POST to debug and see what you actually get.

Comment: @RamRaider I checked the XHR Request Payload and I'm able to see the file name of the file I selected. I've added the Request Payload results above. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @CBroe I tried your suggestion but I keep getting `NULL` or `array(0){}` I've added the edits above. Any other suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: Try `var formData = new FormData( $('#modalForm_uploadVideo')[0] );`, and remove anything else where you try to append stuff manually.

Comment: I just found the reason why it always returns null. I switched to Windows OS from Ubuntu and it showed the error. The problem was simply because of `post_max_size` :( I didn't have to spend that much of time. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

You're sending the file data in the `file` property, not `myFile`, so your PHP should be changed to this:

```
$myFile = $_FILES['file']['name']; // note 'file' here
echo "myFile: " . $myFile;
```